# Error al actualizar PPT con Python

Tags: python

quisiera saber si alguien puede ayudarme con este error.
Estoy creando un archivo .pptx con python. Cuando quiero actualizar este archivo creado, me aparece el siguiente error

```
File "C:.....\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 940, in _update_crc
raise BadZipFile("Bad CRC-32 for file %r" % self.name)
```

zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'ppt/media/image60.png'

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Tendrías que revisar que el archivo `ppt/media/image60.png` no esté dañado (por ejemplo, mirandolo en pantalla)

Comment: Por favor, añade el código que genera este error. Los pptx, docx y xlsx son esencialmente archivos zip con toda la info en  varios archivos dentro. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).